# I am not able to redirect on sign up page,it is redirecting me to my login page instead sign up page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, routeparams

```
 this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  console.log('params value===>',params );
  value = params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
  // new chaanges for sso -auth
  console.log('value===>',value );
  if(value){
  try {
    
    let bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(value,'#Alignor Credentials#');
 
    this.resAuth = JSON.parse(bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
    console.log('resAuth==>',this.resAuth);
    if(this.resAuth.comm_id || this.resAuth.community_id){
      this.checkForSSOAUTH(this.resAuth.comm_id ? this.resAuth.comm_id : this.resAuth.community_id);
      let obj={
       comm_id :this.resAuth.comm_id ? this.resAuth.comm_id : this.resAuth.community_id
     }
```

I have written this code ,when I am trying to redirect its not redirecting me to sign up page,going directly to login page and geeting error

Comment: Hi Anisa, What kinda error you get?

Comment: in value its getting undefined for 'value'